# Alternatives for Transparent redirect in Braintree

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, braintree

Instead of transparent redirect is there a way so that redirect is done to Braintree and they take care of payment ?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I work at Braintree</sub>

While Braintree doesn't offer any hosted pages solutions, their partners do. Depending on your billing model, you could use something like [Chargify](http://chargify.com/) for recurring billing or [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) for one time purchases.

Braintree easily plugs into these services to help power their out-of-the box solutions.